# Performing Search inside a folder using portal_catalog excluding root folder

Tags: python, plone

I am performing a search inside a folder. Unfortunately, it retrieves also the root folder, and I do not want that.

An example is as follows. If I have a directory structure similar to the one below:

```
RootFolder
    ... SubFolder1
    ... SubFolder2
```

I expect to get the following when I search inside `RootFolder` directory:

```
SubFolder1
SubFolder2
```

But instead, this is what I get:

```
RootFolder
SubFolder1
SubFolder2
```

I do not want the root to be displayed. Below is the code that I use to fetch/search the items within a folder:

```
def queryItemRepository(self):
    """
    Perform a search
    """

    query = {}

    portal_catalog = getToolByName(self, 'portal_catalog')
    folder_path = '/'.join( self.context.getPhysicalPath() )

    query['path'] = {'query' : folder_path, 'depth' : 2 }
    query['sort_on'] = "sortable_title"
    query['sort_order'] = "ascending"

    return portal_catalog.searchResults(query)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `depth` parameter in path searches limits the depth of the search, it does not set a minimal level. So, in your search, all paths starting at `folder_path` up to and including 2 nested levels of children are returned.

Just filter out the root path; you already have the context so you can just compare URL of each item:

```
for match in portal_catalog.searchResults(query):
    if match.getPath() == folder_path:
        continue
    yield match
```